# Write PDF with resulting data?

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, pdf

I am trying to write two value  to a PDF. I am able to write the first row to Copay Paid1 and total paid1, but i cant write the secound row to Copay Paid2 and total paid2. How am i able to write the second row to Copay Paid2 and total paid2.

sample SQL data

[image]

sample of code

```
void miCopayReceipt_Click(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr;         
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = Application.WebService.ExecuteQuery("pat_reprintCoPayReceipt",
                  new SPParam[] {
                                    new SPParam("@ApptId",currentAppt.ApptId)
                                });
                dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];


        cb.BeginText();
        string s = "";
        s = "Total Paid1:";
        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, s, 75, 595, 0);
        cb.EndText();

        cb.BeginText();
        string textLine = Convert.ToDouble(dr["PaymentAmount"]).ToString("C");
        textLine += "    Copay Paid1: " + Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CopayAmount"]).ToString("C");


        cb.BeginText();
        string s = "";
        s = "Total Paid 2:";
        cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, s, 75, 595, 0);
        cb.EndText();

        cb.BeginText();
        string textLine = Convert.ToDouble(dr["PaymentAmount"]).ToString("C");
        textLine += "    Copay Paid2: " + Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CopayAmount"]).ToString("C");
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing an cb.EndText() call after writing the Copy Paid1 line, or maybe an extra beginText()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one or two `EndText()` calls. Apparantly the control you're using demands an `EndText()` call to start a new line, or write the text at all.

Also you're storing the first row in `dr`. If you want to store a second row, you should declare a second `DataRow` or overwrite the `dr` with the second row as soon as you're done with the first row.

```
    cb.BeginText();
    string textLine = Convert.ToDouble(dr["PaymentAmount"]).ToString("C");
    textLine += "    Copay Paid1: " + Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CopayAmount"]).ToString("C");
    cb.EndText(); // Added this

    // Get the second row
    if(dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Length > 0)
        dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1];

    cb.BeginText();
    string s = "";
    s = "Total Paid 2:";
    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, s, 75, 595, 0);
    cb.EndText();

    cb.BeginText();
    string textLine = Convert.ToDouble(dr["PaymentAmount"]).ToString("C");
    textLine += "    Copay Paid2: " + Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CopayAmount"]).ToString("C");
    cb.EndText(); // Added this
```

Comment: ok just added it, but it is not getting the second row from sql still. it is only getting the first row.

Comment: See my updated answer, missed that one. It might be that the .Length property is invalid and that it should be `.Count` or `.Count()`

Comment: i dont have ds in my current context

Comment: Then, create a new DataRow object, for example `dr2` and assign `ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]` on the same place where you assign `dr`.